# Why is this query failing in hosting sites?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

I have this query:

```
$get_active_image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM media WHERE media_type = 'image' 
AND range = 'global' ORDER BY news_id DESC LIMIT 0,1");
```

and it works just perfectly fine in my localhost.

But, when I tried uploading it in freehosting sites, it gives me this error message:

> supplied argument is not valid

It seems that in my query, WHERE and AND cannot come together, because *the query works* if I remove the **AND**  - plus -  I am 100% sure *range GLOBAL* exists, as said, it works in my localhost.

I just wanna know why it's not working when I host it.

Also, database connection is 100% working. Nothing else is wrong. Just the query with the **AND** doesn't work.

If I miss something, please enlighten me. Thank you.

Comment: It could be any number of things. Are you doing any error checking? `if (!$get_active_image) echo mysql_error()`

Comment: With the issue being caused by your hosting environment, it maybe important to mention which hosting environment you are using.

Comment: First, all `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. You should consider PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: Yes I did error check. The query returns empty if I'm using that query (with the AND clause) else... if I remove it.. I use this instead: $get_active_image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM media WHERE media_type = 'image' ORDER BY news_id DESC LIMIT 0,1"); it works just fine.

Comment: I tried Byehost24 and 000webhost - it's the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Range` is a reserved word.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Try adding backticks around it.

```
$get_active_image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM media WHERE media_type = 'image' 
AND `range` = 'global' ORDER BY news_id DESC LIMIT 0,1");
```

It may work on your local host due to a different version of MySQL in which it is NOT a reserved word.

Comment: Indeed. Do show an example in your answer. It will be beneficial.

Comment: `RANGE` is a reserved word since MySQL 5.1; it was not in MySQL 5.0.

Comment: Done it. @Jessica if you like it better that way. And you're welcome. `+1` cheers.

Comment: `Another Happy Ending`